# My pc switchs on from itself

Tags: suspend, power-management, laptop, battery

I don't know how and when, but if I put the pc in standby or I switch it off without charging, when I switch it on in the morning it is already on (but with the standby screen) and without charge (even if i didn't charged it because i switched off when it was at 90%).
A particulat thing that happened was when i closed the lid to put it in standby and during the night it started to reproduce the movie that was in pause loudly.
I have an Acer Swift 3 SF314-511  with Ubuntu 22.04 updated

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: There is many number of reasons as to why a laptop or desktop could wake up or power on by itself.  BIOS settings set to a certain wake up time.  Wake On LAN enabled causing a certain type of packet to hit the network card in the system and turn it back on or wake it from sleep.  An application that didn't shutdown all the way (but this will not cause a power on, but more of a wake from sleep.).  Lid switch settings not enabled right to put the system into sleep mode.  Maybe consider using hibernate instead of sleep.

Comment: thank you! and how can i understan which one of these is the problem? and about the hibernate solution: my ubuntu version doesn't give me the option, i've tried installing the extension but when i click on it it fails the proces of hibernation